# tty works, but cannot run programs

Tags: debian, tty

So, I went poking around at `/dev/ttyS0` and `/dev/ttyUSB0`, trying to get some ham radio accessories working, and broke it. `ttyS0` controls the radio transmission, and if I run cat `/dev/ttyS0` as the normal user, the radio transmits.

However, if I run the modem software (FLdigi), which previously worked with the radio using `ttys0`, it doesn't work. When starting the program, there is a message in the log saying "failed serial port test." I'm in both "dialout" and "uucp" groups, so I think it should be working.

One thing I remember running is `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyS0`. I'm not sure what I should set that back to. Any ideas on why I can access it while the software I run can't, even though it's both from the same user?

Comment: (1) Are you sure the error message `failed serial port test` indicates inability to use the serial port? My guess is that is actually indicates that the software failed to interact with the radio using some bidirectional communication protocol.

Comment: (2) You make references in your question to both `/dev/ttyS0` and to `/dev/ttys0`. Almost certainly, only the former is actually correct, and if you are using `/dev/ttys0` instead of `/dev/ttyS0` then that could obviously be the source of the problem.

Comment: The software uses t/dev/ttyS0. I fired up a different program that utilizes the same port, and it no longer works either. So it looks like something I changed regarding the port made it inaccessible for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

- Check whether no applications have the port open when you want to use it.
- Check whether there are no messages in the kernel log (use `dmesg`).
- Check what exactly is happening in your application - run it  under `strace` which will report syscalls that the application makes. You probably want tu use something like:

  ```
  $ strace -f -s 512 -o /path/to/application.log.strace application ...
  ```

which will also `strace` children processes, log strings ap to their 512th byte and all that will end up in `/path/to/application.log.strace`, the ellipsis stands for possible arguments for application. You can also tell `strace` to attach to a running process identified by PID (`-p` argument). See the `strace(1)` man page for more information. Rather towards the end of the log you should be able to find a `write()` call that prints the error message. Chances are that *relatively* shortly before that will be an `open()` or `write()` (on the device file) that returned -1. That might give you some idea of what is the reason of the error.

As a side note regarding permissions: you don't want to use `chmod 777`, since that makes the file executable and that is never a good idea with anything else then executables and directories. For device files (depending on their nature) reasonable values are 0640 or 0660 which allows full access for root and either read or read-write access for group (of which the user in question should be a member to gain the permissions - in your case that is likely the `dialout` group you mention).

In most cases you also want to prepend a zero (e.g. `chmod 0664` since that removes any suid bits, which *usually* is a good idea).